# Excel - Formula To Find Match On List of Keywords?

Tags: excel, macos, excel-formula

If I have colors going from cells B1-B6 (Red, Orange, Yellow, Green,Blue,Purple)

And then a sentence/string in cell A1 - (There was a orange box).

I want a formula in cell C1 where if there is a match on any of the keywords, that is should **spit out the keyword it matched**. Attached is a screenshot example.

I would also want this formula in C1 to be able to drag down and have it "auto-fill". So that if I put any sentence in cell A2, it should repeat the formula in C1, but for this new cell of A2 automatically.

[image: ImageExample]

Comment: Lots of things you can try: find(), or search() or index() with match(). If you look on here you will find examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula:

=XLOOKUP(1,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1:B6,A1)),B1:B6,"no match",2) in the "C" Column.

it will work!

[image: Solution]

Comment: You can change the Column B as absolute reference using the formula =XLOOKUP(1,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B:$B,A1)),$B:$B,"no match",2)